# Delete String from text file fails on deployment in tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, netbeans, file-io

As per the captioned subject, I am not able to delete String from a text file on deployment in tomcat. Although it works absolutely fine in netbeans or eclipse.
When application is deployed it always says 'could not delete file'. Also I am not able to manually delete the file as I get 'Cannot delete file: It is in use by some other programs'.
But I am able to append String to this same text file.
This is the code that I am using to delete String from the file.

```
    package com.pro.model;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class RemoveLine {

    private String inputFileName = "D:\\Marquee\\Copy of Scroll.txt";

    public boolean deleteData(String msg, int pos) throws IOException {

        //List msg_remove = null;
        System.out.println("msg :" + msg);
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
            File tempFile = new File("D:\\myTempFile.txt");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
            String lineToRemove = msg;
            String currentLine;
            while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
                String[] trimmedLine = currentLine.split("\\|");
                System.out.println("currentLine :" + currentLine);
                System.out.println("trimmedLine :" + trimmedLine.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < trimmedLine.length; i++) {
                    int k = i + 1;
                    System.out.println("Calculating the size of field " + k);
                    //writer.write("Column " + k + " is " + trimmedLine[i].length());
//                    is.flush();
//                    is.newLine();
                    System.out.println("trimmedLine[i] :" + trimmedLine[i]);
                    //writer.write(trimmedLine[i] + "|");
                    System.out.println("trimmedLine[i].equals(lineToRemove) :" + trimmedLine[i].equals(lineToRemove));
                    //if (trimmedLine[i].equals(lineToRemove)) {
                    if (i == pos) {
                        System.out.println("trimmedLine in if:" + trimmedLine[i]);
                        //writer.flush();
                        //trimmedLine.replaceAll(currentLine, "");
                        continue;
                    }
                    System.out.println("currentLine :" + currentLine);
                    //writer.write(currentLine + "|");
                    writer.write(trimmedLine[i] + "|");
                }
            }
            writer.flush();
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
            if (!inputFile.delete()) {
                System.out.println("Could not delete file");
                return false;
            }

            //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
            if (!tempFile.renameTo(inputFile)) {
                System.out.println("Could not rename file");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
            //boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public List readText() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        List msg_after_removed = new ArrayList();

        try {
            File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
            //File tempFile = new File("C:\\myTempFile.txt");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));

            //msg_after_removed = new ArrayList();

            if (inputFile.exists()) {
                //data = msg1;

                FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(inputFile.getPath(), true);
                System.out.println("file.getName():" + inputFile.getName());
                System.out.println("file.getName():" + inputFile.getPath());

                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
                String currentLine;
                while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] trimmedLine = currentLine.split("\\|");
                    for (int i = 0; i < trimmedLine.length; i++) {
                        Bean getdata = new Bean();
                        System.out.println("trimmedLine in read ==" + trimmedLine[i] + i + "=length=" + trimmedLine.length);
                        getdata.setMsg(trimmedLine[i]);
                        String arr[] = trimmedLine[i].split(":");
                        System.out.println("arr[] in read" + arr[1]);
                        getdata.setDate(arr[0]);
                        getdata.setMsg(arr[1]);
                        msg_after_removed.add(getdata);
                        //reader.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Bean getdata = new Bean();
            getdata.setDate("0");
            getdata.setMsg("0");
            msg_after_removed.add(getdata);
            System.out.println("in catch");
            //reader.close();
            //return false;
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }
        return msg_after_removed;
    }
}
```

I thought maybe Read stream is not closing properly & that is why I am not able to delete/save file manually. But if that was the case, I should also not be able to append String to the file.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What line? Elaborate.

Comment: I am developing an application which will append String to text file and allow for users to view messages and delete message that is not required. I need to delete this String. It works perfectly when I run it from Netbeans or Eclipse...but fails on deployment. Am I missing something? Do File-io need any dependencies to be added on deployment?? String to be deleted will be in msg array.

Comment: Your project residing in C: drive ?.If yes , change the location of project and try again.